# REST HATEOAS: How can client discover Uri or future action for filter applied on client application?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, api-design, restful-url, hateoas

The Wiki page for REST constraint HATEOAS [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS] suggests:

"A REST client enters a REST application through a simple fixed URL. All future actions the client may take are discovered within resource representations returned from the server."

We are creating a search page for products like e-commerce website. We are currently giving user 1. option to filter products by budget i.e. input minimum and maximum budget and 2. option to filter out "Out of stock" products.

Currently, when someone enters a minimum and maximum budget, the client creates following Uri to fetch the list of products:

/api/products/?budget={min}-{max} i.e. /api/products/?budget=1-3

Or if someone selects to exclude "Out of stock" products, the client creates following Uri to fetch the list of products:

/api/products/?outofstock=false

I feel we are violating HATEOAS principle by hard-coding these links at every client as HATEOAS suggest that client should discover all resources except for a simple fixed URL. Is it really a violation or it's the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have modeled `/products` as a REST resource representing a collection of multiple products.  Both `budget` and `outofstock` are filtering query parameters that restrict the products returned.

You could potentially use URI templates as defined in [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) to announce to clients that your REST API supports these query parameters.

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "products",
            "href": "/products{?budget,outofstock}"
        }
    ]
}
```

That would announce to clients the presence of those parameters, but not necessarily the data types of the values they accept.  My understanding is that the standards are not as formalized around specifying data types as values, but there are options such as [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html) for trying to specify that information.  Last I checked, this was an IETF draft.

Another option is for the response to include specialized links pre-populated with relevant query parameters.  Clients could provide navigation to these links without needing to hard-code awareness of the specific query parameters the service is using.

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "budget-low",
            "href": "/products?budget=1-3"
        },
        {
            "rel": "in-stock",
            "href": "/products?outofstock=false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: when should this be announced to the client, with the collection of response?

Comment: The `products` link could be announced in the response from the "simple fixed URL" as stated in your question.  If your response from `/products` includes a `"rel": "self"` link back to `/products`, then you could put the parameters in the URI template there too.

Comment: what is the benefit of passing all filter parameter names in the "href", as number of filter parameters would too many. What are we achieving by this? why not simple hardcode these? is it only to provide flexibility to change uri in future?

Comment: Your question statement concerns "violating HATEOAS principle by hard-coding".  Specifying the filter parameters in a URI template is a way to avoid that hard-coding.  Whether or not this is truly beneficial to your clients is a design decision, but this is a potential tool to achieve it.

Comment: Agreed. But I believe it's lot of effort to avoid hard coding. As number of filters would grow i.e. filter like companies like samsung,nokia, the filter list would become too long and would be difficult.

Comment: I had one more thought: pre-populated links in the responses that navigate to interesting combinations of the query parameters.  Answer updated.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel we are violating HATEOAS principle by hard-coding these links at every client as HATEOAS suggest that client should discover all resources except for a simple fixed URL. Is it really a violation?

Yes.

The HATEOAS approach is that you build knowledge of the *semantics* into the client, and then the client searches the representation for the appropriate semantics and follows whatever link is found there.

You can get a REST design by thinking about how you would do this on a web site with human consumers.  You'd tell them the bookmark, and when they loaded that page they would see hyperlinks with text telling them what each link was for.  Clicking on the link for your ranged search would take them to a form, and the text labels would tell them what each field was for.  They would fill out and submit the form, which (for a GET) would construct a URI as described in the specification for the html media type, and they would get results. back.

That's hypermedia at work.  Start from there, then add machine readable cues so that a client can find the links in the representation.

> Can you share some link/example where something has been built keeping all this in mind

For a time, the [Sun Cloud API](https://web.archive.org/web/20170123214915/http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/Home) was a favorite demonstration of a hypermedia API.

For examples in current general use, [RFC 4287: Atom Syndication Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) and [RFC 5023: Atom Publication Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) might be your best bet.

> I want to design things like this but unable to get how exactly "html media type" can be achieved to do this?

Creating your own custom media type?  You can do that; but it's probably going to be more effective to use one of the existing hypermedia formats ([HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/), [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/)...) Kevin Sookocheff wrote an [overview (2014)](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) of several types.

Comment: That looks useful. Can you share some link/example where something has been built keeping all this in mind. I want to design things like this but unable to get how exactly "html media type" can be achieved to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of HATEOAS is to keep the server in control of the URL space. The benefit is making clients more resilient to backwards incompatible changes. The question is how much resilience do you require.

1. If your clients are forced to hardcode the whole URL, there's zero resilience. Any URL changes will break clients.
2. If your clients get the base URL but hardcode the URL parameters, you can make changes to the base path but you can't make changes to the parameters or query semantics.
3. If your server is returning URL templates with the base URL and query parameters, your clients are much more resilient to changes, but you still can't change query semantics if the clients are choosing the parameters at will. For instance, let's say your clients are making one particular query very often and you decide to provide a separate URL with optimizations or even a static resource. The clients won't start using it immediately and client developers will have to change the code and parameters used, even if you're providing them in the URL template.
4. If your server provides separate links or URL templates with fixed parameters for all relevant queries, you can change them at will, anytime you want, without breaking clients, but it takes a lot more work.

So, if you just want to do HATEOAS as an end in itself, then do 4. That's how it should be done. If you have a real problem to solve, then don't worry about violating HATEOAS and ask yourself how much resilience you need and how much work you can put into that.

Note that there's nothing forcing you to use the same approach in the whole API or even the same resource. For instance, you can use option 3 to provide more flexible queries, and option 4 to provide some common queries you might want to optimize in the future.

Keep in mind that all your effort into getting HATEOAS right will be pointless if clients don't use it. If they hardcode URLs instead of using the links, your changes will break them, even if you worked hard to avoid that. This might be a problem or not, depending on your company culture.